# How to get ordered index of item in DynamoDB using Query?

Tags: key, amazon-dynamodb

Consider I have a table with items. Items have hash key (key) and range key (date). As DynamoDB docs say range keys assume ordering items. Is it possible to get an index of a particular item in that ordered set, without the need to query all preceded items.

Example:

```
A{
    key:1
    date:01.01.2015
}
B{
    key:1
    date:01.02.2015
}
C{
    key:1
    date:01.03.2015
}
```

Querying only C, without querying all other items, I want to know that C is the third item in an ordered set formed by range key date with a hash key 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Count](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Count) API call.

With the correct filter: [lower-equals](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) you could count the elements before and including the one you need, thus providing an ordered index to it.